# Как протестировать платёж в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, платежи

https://cdn.tranzzo.com/tranzzo-api/index.html#create-hosted-payment
Подскажите, как можно протестировать платёж?
Как в `woocommerce` отправить данный запрос с помощью `php`?

```
$ curl -i "https://cpay.tranzzo.com/api/v1/payment" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-API-AUTH: CPAY ${API_KEY}:${API_SECRET}" \
-H "X-API-KEY: ${ENDPOINTS_KEY}" \
-X POST -d '{
      "pos_id":           "${POS_ID}",
      "mode":             "hosted",
      "method":           "purchase",
      "amount":           1,
      "currency":         "UAH",
      "description":      "description_1",
      "order_id":         "123",
      "order_3ds_bypass": "always",
      "server_url":       "https://callback.blackhole.com/callback",
      "result_url":       "https://example.com/result",
      "payload":          "sale=true"
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<?php

$api_key       = '';
$api_secret    = '';
$endpoints_key = '';
$pos_id        = '';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cpay.tranzzo.com/api/v1/payment' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    '{
    "pos_id":           "' . $pos_id . '",
    "mode":             "hosted",
    "method":           "purchase",
    "amount":           1,
    "currency":         "UAH",
    "description":      "description_1",
    "order_id":         "123",
    "order_3ds_bypass": "always",
    "server_url":       "https://callback.blackhole.com/callback",
    "result_url":       "https://example.com/result",
    "payload":          "sale=true"
    }'
);

$headers   = [];
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-API-AUTH: CPAY ' . $api_key . ':' . $api_secret;
$headers[] = 'X-API-KEY: ' . $endpoints_key;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error( $ch );
}

curl_close( $ch );
```

Задайте значения четырём переменным в начале кода.